# Execution failed for task ':stack_appodeal_flutter:compileDebugKotlin'

Tags: flutter, kotlin, appodeal

After upgrading, I have this error. How can I resolve this error?

```
Launching lib/main.dart on SM G970F in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
e: /Users/myMac/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/stack_appodeal_flutter-1.2.0/android/src/main/kotlin/com/appodeal/appodeal_flutter/AppodealAdViewFactory.kt: (9, 10): Class 'AppodealAdViewFactory' is not abstract and does not implement abstract base class member public abstract fun create(p0: Context?, p1: Int, p2: Any?): PlatformView defined in io.flutter.plugin.platform.PlatformViewFactory
e: /Users/myMac/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/stack_appodeal_flutter-1.2.0/android/src/main/kotlin/com/appodeal/appodeal_flutter/AppodealAdViewFactory.kt: (12, 5): 'create' overrides nothing

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is beacause the current [stack_appodeal_flutter] package is not compatible with Flutter 3.0.
I have the same problem and contacted the support team at Appodeal. they told me to wait for around two weeks for new package which will be compatible with Flutter 3.0.

hope it will help you.

Comment: Yes, they told me too. I didn't manage to put it here.

Comment: Any feedback on this? Currently stack_appodeal_flutter package is at version 3.0.0